# Is it possible to open pdf file from mobile browser instead on download?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

In my web application, I have file response from server as byte[] content and open it with this code

```
let file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL);
```

It's working perfectly fine on a laptop browser. but when I try with chrome on mobile, It always downloads the file instead of open it.

I also try to set the target as "_system" but this also not work.

Is there any way to make it open in mobile browser instead of download?

Comment: This is dependent on the behavior of the user agent (browser and system) and there is very little you can do about it as a web developer.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on browser but if you want always preview rather than download then you can use library for it

```
npm i ng2-pdf-viewer
```

usage is easy [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-pdf-viewer?file=src/app/app.component.html) just give src to its ui element

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="src" ></pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. I will try to go with this.